# How editable and no editable field in text box according to role

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, model-view-controller

I am working with ASP.NET in a web application What I want to do is that when you enter the system, depending on the user, some input text is enabled. For example, if the user is an administrator, all the input texts are enabled but if they are a normal user, all are disabled.

It is necessary to keep in mind that you used session variables depending on the type of user:

- Session["typeUser"] (String)

  - user
  - admin
  - technical
  - helpdesk

I was consulted and can be done with this function

**@HttpContext.Current.Session["typeUser"].ToString();**

This is the code  **cshtml** of the form where the fields that I want are not editable. Within this form I do not want the first three fields to be editable: Enrollment, Full Name and Email

```
<form id="InformationUser" class="contact-form">
                        <div class="box-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Enrollment">Enrollment</label>
                                <input type="text" name="Enrollment" class="form-control" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Full name">Full name:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="Full name" class="form-control" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Email">Email:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Extension">Extension:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="extension" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Area">Area:</label>
                                <select name="area" class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" style="width: 100%;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"></select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Ubicacion">Ubicacion:</label>
                                <select name="ubicacion" class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" style="width: 100%;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"></select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some javascript at the end to do the job for you.  Assuming you have razor view engine, this should give you some idea of how to approach it:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   var role = @HttpContext.Current.Session["typeUser"].ToString();

   switch (role){
    case "user" :
      document.getElementByName("Enrollment").disabled=true;  // or whatever
   break;


}

</script>
```

Comment: I execute the code that you left me and get an exception System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not established as an instance of an object.